# Как ходить по древу JSON? (Python)

Tags: python, json

Цель: вывести из всех элементов (entities) поля "subject" --> "name" + "number" из json запроса

Отрывок запроса:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "school": {
        "id": 254044,
        "name": "МАОУ \"Учебное заведение №1\" г.Города"
      },
      "subject": {
        "id": 1470,
        "name": "Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности",
        "sysname": "OBJ"
      },
      "number": 1
    },
    {
      "school": {
        "id": 254044,
        "name": "МАОУ \"Учебное заведение №1\" г.Города"
      },
      "subject": {
        "id": 1133,
        "name": "Математика",
        "sysname": "Mt"
      },
      "number": 2
    }
  ],
  "totalCount": 32
}
```

То есть, вывод должен быть:

```
1. Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности
2. Математика
```

Застрял на этом этапе проекта, гуглил до невозможности, help me please :)

Comment: Посмотрите этот урок https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIhygmw9HZM  тут все доходчиво.

Comment: Внутри `json` словари и списки. Списки - перебирать через `for`, у словарей брать значения по нужным ключам. И всё это может быть вложено друг в друга много раз что угодно во что угодно. Но принцип один.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспольховаться методом [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) для преобразования JSON в объект Python. Объект вы можете "обойти" с помощью индексации и цикла [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

```py
import json

s = r'{"entities":[{"school":{"id":254044,"name":"МАОУ \"Учебное заведение №1\" г.Города"},"subject":{"id":1470,"name":"Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности","sysname":"OBJ"},"number":1},{"school":{"id":254044,"name":"МАОУ \"Учебное заведение №1\" г.Города"},"subject":{"id":1133,"name":"Математика","sysname":"Mt"},"number":2}],"totalCount":32}'
tree = json.loads(s)

for entity in tree['entities']:
    number = entity['number']
    name = entity['subject']['name']
    print(f'{number}. {name}')
```

***stdout:***

```py
1. Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности
2. Математика
```